# How to connect component in html props in react-tippy to redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have got a problem with react-tippy component. I would like to pass in html props react component with redux form, but I receive an error like this:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Form(AssignDriverForm))". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Form(AssignDriverForm))".
```

Here is code of react tippy component:

```
class AssignDriverToolTip extends Component {
    state = { open: false }
    setIsOpen = () => this.setState({ open: true });
    setIsClose = () => this.setState({ open: false });

    render() {
        return (
            <CustomTooltip
                theme="light"
                open={this.state.open}
                arrow={false}
                html={(
                    <AssignDriverForm/>
                )}
                position='right'
                trigger="click" >
                <CustomButton infoSmallWithIcon onClickHandler={() => this.setIsOpen()}>
                    <SVGComponent icon="pen" color="white" width="12px" height="12px" />
                    {strings.assignDriver}
                </CustomButton>
            </CustomTooltip>
        )
    }
}
export default AssignDriverToolTip;
```

And also here is an AssignDriverForm component:

```
class AssignDriverForm extends Component {
    handleSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Field
                    name="message"
                    type="textarea"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    component="textarea" />
            </form>
        )
    }
}

AssignDriverForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'assignDriver'
})(AssignDriverForm)

export default AssignDriverForm;
```

When I change it to component without redux-form everything works fine. But I really dont know how to fix it. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says: find the root component where you create your store. (Something like this in index.jx)

```
const store = createStore(reducer)
```

Then make sure you wrap your component in the `<Provider>` wrapper.

```
// render app
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Redux form uses a normal Redux store, so somewhere you need to add that reducer to your main reducer. You may have something like this:

```
// combine reducers
const reducer = combineReducers({
  myReducer,
  ...
  form: formReducer // for redux-form
})
```